# How to get all files but exclude some files in .sh?

Tags: sh

for example:
I have A.cpp, B.cpp, C.cpp Main.cpp, A_Test.cpp, B_Test.cpp, I want a script to compile and run Main.cpp but would not compile .cpp files that contains "Test"

now this script would compile all cpp files

```
#!/bin/ksh
g++ *.cpp -o $1.exe
./$1.exe
```

how to modify codes so that it can filter some files?

Comment: Is it outside the realm of possibility to use a makefile? http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/  -  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to match all files *not* matching your regex

```
 FILES=$(ls <path>/*.cpp | grep -v Test&)
 g++ ${FILES} -o $1.exe
```